# Bug in sorting by newest questions and filtering by tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app, newest-questions

Identical to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/bug-sorting-by-one-tag-and-newest-questions

I am using android stackexchange app version 1.0.43 , android version 4.1.2

For example I was searching by newest questions with a specific tag and below is what I got

> [image]

I tried without tag still same result

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a silly bug that has bothered me for awhile.  The date you are seeing here is the last activity date.  After the next build you will see the creation date when sorting by newest, and the last activity date when sorting by anything else.